# How to import word documents into Elastic Search

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, apache-poi, nutch, apache-tika

I am trying to import contents of word document into elastic. What are my options to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The recommendation is to use the [ingest attachment processor plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.3/ingest-attachment.html)

Answer (score 0):

[FSCrawler](https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/) also seems to be an option, though I haven't used it personally.